What is the correct way to use C23's nullptr in place of NULL?
I've been playing around with C23's new features and I came across nullptr, and I'd like to use it in place of NULL where possible, or at least in demo code to better understand proper usage.
Here is an example of some code where I tried to replace NULL with nullptr, as you might do in C++:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    int* ptr = &x;
    if(ptr != nullptr) {
        printf("ptr not null!");
    }
}

I'm using gcc 13.2.0, which should support C23's nullptr. Surprisingly, compilation fails with or without the -std=c2x flag.
Here is the error gcc gives:
nullptr.c: In function 'main':
nullptr.c:7:15: error: 'nullptr' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'nullptr_t'?
    7 |     if(ptr != nullptr) {
      |               ^~~~~~~
      |               nullptr_t
nullptr.c:7:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Replacing nullptr with the type nullptr_t doesn't make sense, it's looking for an expression before a type name like nullptr_t, and indeed that is what happens.
I can get a successful compilation and expected behavior with simple casting NULL to nullptr_t:
if(ptr != (nullptr_t)NULL)

My assumption is that this is not the proper or intended usage of C23's nullptr, and there's something I'm missing.

The docs say the flag is -std=c23.

I mentioned I am using gcc 13.2.0, which does not have -std=c23. The equivalent is -std=c2x. On the demo, with gcc 13.2, it compiles and works as expected with -std=c2x. Not sure what could be causing the failed compilation locally.

@jitters I just noticed that you mentioned 13.2 specifically. You are right that for 13.2 the flag is -std=c2x. But it works on Godbolt: demo, so I also do not know why it does not work for you locally. How about upgrading to 14.2 (supports -std=c23) ?

nullptr was introduced in C++11, and the default dialect in GCC 13 is gnu++17, so I do not know why it did not compile for you. The change made in C++23 is to make it a constant, not a prvalue. Read more here.

@Dúthomhas Note that this post is about C not C++.

Crud. Why do I always miss that?

Upgrading gcc did the trick. That was a weird one. Thanks.

Please write up that answer.

"I'd like to use it in place of NULL where possible" Why? Nobody seems to understand why nullptr was introduced to C or what purpose it fills. Don't use things just because they are new. What's the rationale here?

It was a terrible mistake that nullptr was added in C23.  Don't use it.  https://software.codidact.com/posts/292718/292759#answer-292759

The C++-like understanding is correct; chalking this up to a versioning issue, since the compilation error was resolved and behavior was as expected when migrating to gcc 14.2 from 13.2.
